# How user friendly & efficient Magento Upgrade?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, versioning

Magento update their version rapidly fast. we are using magento 1.9.2.3, we are moving our entire version from 1.9.2.3 to 2.1.7, after some months magento closed 2.1 series docs. [Magento announce EoQ & EoS for  2.3 series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhn7c.jpg). They update their versions quickly and without giving enough time to develop/upgrade own extensions. In our case we are using more than 15 custom modules, 25K products, 300 Categories and 50K customers. In future how magento stable their version?

Comment: Frankly, Don't move to M2. Choose framework or stay with M1 ;) No offense

Comment: @Vivek Magento officially announced 1.x series support and security closed.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is rapidly upgrading it's versions to make sure they are modular and secure as per the Ecommerce standards and code standards. They have implemented Security Patches, PCI compliances, improved website browsing speed. It is adviceable to upgrade your extensions, theme to magento latest version, which would be good to secure your business. It is also recommended to keep upgrading your magento to make sure all the security patches are implemented to safe your website from hackers and malicious scripts. Once you are done with your Magento 1.9 upgradation to magento 2.3.x, implementing latest upcoming versions would not be that hard. just need to upgrade using command.

Magento is providing a tool to migrate your products, sales and customers from 1.9.x to 2.3.x. All your data can be migrated using this tool.
**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/bk-migration-guide.html**

but extensions and theme need to migrate. Even though there are tools which can migrate your extensions almost 70-80% but some manual intervention would still be needed. https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Magento has also launched Magento2 Commerce Cloud to give you a seamless deployment process, where you can focus on your business only and magento will take care of your Business Infra to give you scalability, 99% up time all the time.

To put it in a nutshell, It is highly recommended always to keep upgrading your magento2 version to the latest one to make sure your business is secure.

Comment: FYI -> Magento officially announced 2.3 series closing date https://i.imgur.com/PMUKtE4.jpg. Does magento 2.3 mudule structure and magento 2.4 module structure is same? We facing really bad, we spend lot of money for upgrade magento 1.9.2.3 to 2.1.7 after few months magenbto closed 2.1.7 docs, this is not professional right. Actually we plan to develop our ecommerce to another domain like Drupal, opqn-cart, Django. We like magento functionality but magento team reapidly updte their version. I dont know they know about developer cost for upgrade magento version.

Comment: Magento 2.x is improving their security day by day but I haven't seen any change in folder structure from 2.0 to 2.3. I have developed modules in 2.0 and migrated the website to 2.2.4, with same module structure without failure. Yes, the obsolete methods needs to rewrite. Even my 2.2.4 website is migrated to 2.3.2 successfully without any module change. 


So, even magento knows very well that keep changing folder structure will not be good for their business model too, so I would say dont worry about the structure. Yes, they have closed magento 2.1 support and soon 2.2 will be closed too.

Comment: Right now, it is even not declared that magento 2.3 and magento 2.4 module structure will be same or different but I am assuming 99% it will remain same because changing structure means the whole market needs to change which is a huge step.

Comment: The update from 1.9 to 2.0+ is a massive effort because M1 and M2 are completely different architectures. The changes between M2 releases are smaller, and incompatibilities are well documented. Some features may be deprecated, but few (well written) customizations should require more than small patches.